# MySQL: Replication won't work after I change the port to 1574

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I implemented **MySQL Replication** in 2 of my MySQL Servers. I have a `master(port:3306)` and `slave(port:3306)`. Everything works fine until I change the slave port to `1574`. Replication won't work anymore!

How to fix this one?

Comment: I found similar question and solution [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86042/mysql-replication-for-non-standard-port-3306.) . This might help you.

Comment: *"won't work anymore!"* **is not** a sufficient description of your problem.  What, specifically, happens?  What error do you see in `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;`, for example?